# como eliminar todas las etiquetas html en sql server

Tags: sql

hola a todos necesito eliminar todas las etiquetas html de un campo en mi base de datos, tengo un código pero solo elimina a veces, quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de eliminar todas las etiquetas html
a continuacion mi codigo que funciona solo a veces

```
 SELECT x.value(' . ', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)' ) as Descripcion,  NombreServicio 
    FROM (
     SELECT x = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(replace( ps.Descripcion ,'<li>','||||| • '),'</p>','|||||'),'-','|||||'),'<br>','|||||'),'',''), '>', '/>'), '</', '<'),'&nbsp;','')AS XML
     ) , NombreServicio = ca.NombreServicio

    FROM CotizacionAuto ca
        INNER JOIN  ProductoServicio ps
        ON ps.IdProductoServicio=ca.IdProductoServicio
    WHERE IdCotizacion=40300) r
```

y el texto que tengo es algo asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no tienen nada que ver el lenguaje, disculpa si no esta bien explicado....lo que pasa es que tengo ese texto (que esta en la imagen) en un campo dentro de mi base de datos, mediante una consulta quiero eliminar todas las etiquetas y solo mostrar texto plano

Comment: desde un editor de texto el cual te permite darle estilos al texto(tipo word) en c# mvc ,pero nose si tenga mucho que ver, necesito que se guarde asi porque en la web necesito que me lo muestre con los estilos ingresados.

Comment: uhmm, no creo que necesite eso (no tiene nada que ver el lenguaje) ...nose si no me explico bien.......el texto de la imagen es lo que tengo en un campo de mi base de datos  y eso esta bien, yo mediante un **UNA CONSULTA SELECT** quiero que me salga texto plano en el mismo sql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868364/sql-remove-all-html-tags-in-a-string/38868776

Comment: ¿Solo buscas quitar los tags?

Comment: asi es @PatricioMoracho